# Is this relational approach scalable?

Tags: php, mysql, relationship

I'm working on a task manager application - one aspect of this is project ownership and access permissions. On paper, it makes sense just to make a `project_user_meta` table, like so:

```
REL_ID    USER_ID    PROJECT_ID    NAME                 VALUE
     1          4            17    'owner'              true
    72        209             8    'project_access'     true
   414         17           101    'task_access_only'   14
```

Etc, etc. But, as the scope of this app grows, where projects start to number in the thousands and users number in the tens of thousands, this can get very cumbersome and disorganized. I'm trying hard not to cross the line into "How do I do this better". What I'm wondering is this - what should I be aware of as the scale of this setup increases?

For example, let's say my company decides to make this app public - the users grow above 100k, and the projects grow above 10k. What limitations/shortcomings is this approach going to face on a larger scale?

Comment: Why do you think it is bad organised? I couldn't do this simpler.

Comment: I think a possible downfall with your meta table is that it will continue to grow with new columns until the point where the rows no longer make sense, but then again a strict, relational structure seems suitable for a permission control table. An other interesting approach is WordPress's [Taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) which gives very high flexibility by using a simple concept of composite terms and values. This approach lessens control but you get much flexibility and may save you a lot of extra database table overhead and duplication. It all depends on yur requirements

Comment: @kjetilh thanks - post that as an answer and I'll take it.

Comment: @CodeMoose well honestly I'm not sure how qualified my thoughts are with regards to your system, especially if it will be massive in size. Now in the aftermath I'm thinking it's more important that your system is stable (for example that you're using foreign keys for your tables) and that the architecture suits your needs. Doesn't matter if the tables look disorganized, if it's right:). You would probably get better answers if your Q was more specific.

Comment: @kjetilh thanks for the advice - reworded the question to be a little more targeted.

Comment: It's not impractical to generate 100k rows for users, 10k rows for projects, etc. I suggest you do that.  Tests are better than opinions. (And often a good enough excuse to learn a new scripting language.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be much easier to have all the projects in one db in the beginning, but *if* you outgrow one db server, then you'll be wishing that you split each project into its own db. That's much easier to scale, and also gives you a level of fault tolerance -- one project's misbehavior wouldn't affect the others.